# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{1+1/2+1/3+1/4+\cdots+1/n}$ a geometric series? And what nature has this series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is this a geometric series? And what nature has this series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{1+1/2+1/3+1/4+\cdots+1/n}$$
with $a>0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: Since $H_n$ approximately equals $\log(n)$, you may easily figure it out.

Comment: Hint: it converges when $a=1/4$ but not when $a=1/2$.

Comment: If we have a series of a constant at a power of a function of n, is this considered a geometric series?

Comment: This isn't a geometric series. The summand is not of the form $ar^n.$

Comment: Review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test